# how can i access a vector in Matlab when using anonymous function that requires inputs

Tags: matlab, functional-programming

I am trying to shuffle a vector that is not yet defined
the vector consist of `[0 0 0 ... 0 0 1 2 3 ... (n-zer)]`

- `n`: length of vector
- `zer`: number of zeros at the beginning

like so:

```
PartZeroPartNum=@(zer,n) [zeros(1,zer),1:(n-zer)];
shuffled=@(zer,n) PartZeroPartNum(zer,n)(randperm(n));
```

it does not work as this part

```
PartZeroPartNum(zer,n)(randperm(n))
```

gives the error:

> cannot call or index into temporary array

In contrast, it is working if I do it this way:

```
n=100;
PartZeroPartNum=logical([zeros(1,zer),1:(n-zer)]);
shuffled=@() PartZeroPartNum(randperm(n));
```

Is it possible to shuffle a more versatile vector as I tried to do above? maybe in another way?

The reason is that I need many examples of shuffled vectors so I thought to make this anonymous function first and then take samples easily like so:

```
ShVec= shuffled(50,100);
```

Comment: wouldn't your function be `shuffled=@(zer,n) randomperm(PartZeroPartNum(zer,n))` analogously to your wokring example?

Comment: You cannot index an indexed array with matlab, this is simply not supported. For example if `x = [1 2 3]` you cannot do `x(2:3)(1)` to get the value `2`. You have to store `x(2:3)` first. (but it work with octave)

Comment: Not everything needs to be an anonymous function. You can write a regular named function too!

Comment: If you have the Statistics Toolbox, you should be able to use [`randsample`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html?s_tid=doc_ta) like `shuffled=@(zer,n) randsample(PartZeroPartNum(zer,n),n);`. I say "should" because I'm using Octave, and in Octave your first attempt with `randperm` works. ;)

Comment: @finn it doesn't work. I tried.

Comment: Beaker I'll try. And your comments really make me reconsider my choice of matlab as a platform...

Comment: Octave simply made different choices at certain points. MATLAB is certainly more actively developed. There are numerous toolboxes and functions that have been added to MATLAB recently that I wish I had access to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are better ways to do this, but you could add yet another anonymous function

```
PartZeroPartNum=@(zer,n) [zeros(1,zer),1:(n-excited)];
fIndex = @(x,ii) x(ii);
shuffled=@(zer,n) fIndex(PartZeroPartNum(zer,n), randperm(n));
```

As mentioned in the comments, you would be better to use a function in its own m-file, this would be the most readable option as suggested by Cris.

Comment: Randperm gets *a number* and generate random index vector the length of this number. It doesn't shuffle a given vector

Answer (score 1):

The function call equivalence to `A(index)` is `subsref(A, struct('type', '()', 'subs', {index}))` see [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsref.html).

So you can make your anonymous function

```
PartZeroPartNum=@(zer,n) [zeros(1,zer),1:(n-excited)];
shuffled=@(zer,n) subsref(PartZeroPartNum(zer,n), struct('type', '()', 'subs', {randperm(n)});
```

But I wouldn't do it as it is not very readable.

Comment: Ill check it out lior. It looks pretty ugly but I don't care about readability. Ill just make a lengthy comment.